# How do I retrieve the details of an contact when i click on a contact?

Tags: java, android

I do retrieve the Contacts of phonebook in my application. But how do I get all the details in single Query. kindly provide me the Code.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: i dont think, you can access all the details in single query.

Comment: "kindly provide me the Code."  Kindly wash my car, and also note that SO is not your personal code generation machine.

Comment: Use contentprovider, it will help u

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

Intent intent_contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

Comment: Hi Jaydeep..this will only navigate to phoneBook Directory.. I need Need to "when a contact Name is clicked then I it retrieve the details of that very contact"